# fgrep beginning of line?

Tags: bash, grep, quoting

I'd like to use `fgrep` to handle searching literal words with periods and other meta-characters in `grep`, but I need to ensure the word is at the beginning of the line.

For example, `fgrep 'miss.'` will match `miss.` exactly which is what I want, but also `admiss.` or `co. miss.` which I don't want.

I might be able to escape meta-characters, e.g. `grep '^miss\.'`, but the source is so large, I'm bound to miss something, and then need to run it again (will take the whole night). And in some cases, e.g. `\1`, the escaped code is the one with "meta-meaning".

Any way around this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With GNU `grep` if built with PCRE support and assuming `$string` doesn't contain `\E`, you can do:

```
grep -P "^\Q$string"
```

With `perl`'s [`rindex`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31724503/):

```
perl -sne 'print if rindex($_, $string, 0) == 0' -- -string="$string"
```

With `awk`:

```
S=$string awk 'index($0, ENVIRON["S"]) == 1'
```

Comment: This one works great - liking very much! Some good stuff in `info grep`!

Answer (score 3):

If your data is very large, then `grep` is likely to be faster than more flexible tools such as awk. What I'd do is to quote the special characters in the text and call `grep`.

```
pattern=$(printf '%s\n' "$literal_text" | sed 's/[\[.*^$]/\\&/g')
grep "^$pattern" my-big-file
```

If the text only contains ASCII characters, set the character set to C, so that grep only concerns itself with bytes. In some implementations (such as many versions of GNU grep), multi-byte characters can cause a significant speed penalty.

```
LC_CTYPE=C grep "^$pattern" my-big-file
```

If you want to search an exact whole line, then there's an option for that: `grep -Fx -e "$literal_text"`. But this only matches lines that consist of exactly the specified text, there's no similar way to match lines that start with the specified text.

Answer (score 2):

with `awk`

```
awk -vword='miss.' 'index($0, word) == 1' file
```

For multiple words

```
awk 'BEGIN{for (i=2; i<ARGC; ++i)word[++j]=ARGV[i]; ARGC=2}
    {for (i=1; i<=j; ++i)if (index($0, word[i]) == 1){print; continue}}' file \
    word1 word2 word3
```

I also fancy `python` for this

```
python3 -c 'import sys
words = tuple(sys.argv[1:])
for line in sys.stdin:
  print(line if line.startswith(words) else "", end="")
' <file word1 word2 word3
```

Comment: Note that the `-v` approach doesn't work if the string to search contains backslash characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have too many patterns:

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN {$exp = quotemeta("miss.")} print if /^$exp/'
```

I don't know how to extend this efficiently to `grep -f` (read patterns from file, which you'd do if you had a serious number of patterns to deal with), but [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11493060/2072269) on joining queries seems to be interesting.